# vue-material not work md-src with custom svg icon

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-material

I generate a project using `vue-cli` and then run `vue add vue-material`.
Then I add MdButton and check in the browser

```
// work
<md-button class="md-icon-button">button</md-button>
```

Then I add MdIcon and check in the browser

```
// not work
<md-button class="md-icon-button">
    <md-icon md-src="/assets/icons/svg/telegram.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

The compilation succeeds, but an error appears in the browser

> Uncaught (in promise) The file /assets/icons/svg/telegram.svg is not a
>   valid SVG.

svg is definitely valid! How to fix?

Comment: How about a fiddle?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this recently; as Leonardo mentioned it was due to the newly-added MIME type check.  For some reason, my SVG file was being served up with `Content-Type: text/html`.

To fix it, I had to change my icons to use `require`, which (if I understand correctly) causes it to go through a different loader in Webpack which fixes the MIME type.  (See [here](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/825#issuecomment-343925080) for a bit more info.)  Using OP's example, I would change:

```
<md-icon md-src="/assets/icons/svg/telegram.svg" />
```

to

```
<md-icon :md-src="require('/assets/icons/svg/telegram.svg')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems an issue created because a mime type. 
https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/pull/1942/commits/74c45f2150e7fc978e536dbc03549d0e8abff47c